# Which value goes on which axis in "plot $a$ against $b$"?

Tags: graphing-functions

When the question asks to plot $a$ against $b$, which value should go on which axis?

Comment: One of them goes on each axis. Instruct the reader to turn the paper 90° if he would like it the opposite way around.

Comment: @Henning ... the reader may also need a mirror. `:-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, the sentence

> Plot $y$ versus $x$

means that $y$ is considered as a dependent variable, and $x$ as an independent variable. So $y$ goes on the vertical axis.